# How can I specify a setup.py and use find packages without needing *any* __init__.py?

Tags: python, package, setuptools

Since Python Version 3.3 `__init__.py` is not anymore necessary.

The issue for setuptools was raised here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/97

The issue seemed to be addressed here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/commit/89155abb4222cf5a9dc81120e5c71e26b5af68f9.

I looked into the current documentation of setuptools at the find_package documentation: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#namespace-packages as well as at the documentation on the keywords: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/keywords.html.

I do not see that I can dispose of `__init__.py` in the package directory. Is there any possibility to that with a setup.py using setuptools or is it not possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try using `find_namespace_packages` instead of `find_packages` in your setup file

Comment: @Mandera Now I found this documentation: https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/. I did not find anything on the "readthedocs" of setuptools. So I will follow this guide.

Comment: @Mandera Still, it is confusing that both examples provided still include a `__init__.py`: https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages/tree/master/native

Comment: They have `__init__.py` in subpackages, not the top-level one. You cannot just put an empty folder in Git — it only knows how to operate paths, hence needs actual files to be committed.

Comment: @webknjaz Oh ok, but that means it could be any file, it needn't be `__init__.py`?

Comment: Exactly this ☝️